# PySide (1.1.2), cx_freeze, WinXP, Python 3.3: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, pyside, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze Python 3.3 code that uses PySide libs using cx_freeze and all of that on Windows XP (x86, SP2/3).

The `python setup.py build` runs successfully but the executable throws an `ImportError`:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling [...]

The same builds run perfectly fine on Windows 7 x64 (SP1).

The versions I am using are as follows:

- Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
- cx_Freeze-4.3.1.win32-py3.3
- PySide-1.1.2.win32-py3.3

Both QT DLL libraries get copied to the build folder (`QtCore.dll`, `QtGui.dll`), the library-zip contains both .pyc equivalents in the `PySide` folder/module.

This issue occurs even with the simplest test-code (<strike>and also if the code is run on a "live" Python installation as well</strike>*):

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication("My Application")
    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Using a more up-to-date version of PySide might fix the problem, but since *PySide 1.2.0* introduces a new issue with *cx-freeze* (the file load error) I was wondering if anyone managed to freeze a PySide package on Windows XP stock successfully?

Otherwise will have to wait until PySide 1.2.1 gets published and keep my hopes for that release.

- See my comment: I'm not sure if this really happened during my tests for actually the same reason or for other reasons e.g. the actual module causing the issue in the frozen builds not having installed properly..

Comment: You say the issue occurs when the code is run on a live Python installation? So this is not specific to frozen applications?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said but that must have happened in the heat of the battle when I was testing across different platforms where the actual installation of the module (that ended up being the culprit) might not have installed properly. I didn't reconstruct the scenario again to prove the opposite but that's my theory. I'll set it in braces to avoid confusion, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out there was a simple solution to the issue: A DLL from *another* module in use by the application was missing; copying it into the root build-out folder next to the frozen EXE easily solved the problem.

The best (and probably only) approach of attack to solve these issues probably is to copy all DLLs from used modules into the build dir one by one until the frozen build doesn't throw the error anymore. I couldn't find another way as the stacktrace didn't point to a specific file that failed loading.

If anyone runs into similar issues, I'd be happy to provide extra info.

Comment: People often recommend [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see which DLLs your running application has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past and was able to resolve it by downloading the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)".